# Как подключиться через ssh на сервер?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер

Осваиваю Linux, что-то типа видео-курса. В нем преподаватель подключается на свой сервер с работы, - у меня конечно же такой возможности нет, но попрактиковаться хочется.
В моем распоряжении имеется: ноутбук на Windows, виртуальная машина, Ubuntu Desktop и Ubuntu Server в ней.
Можно ли как-то с помощью этого воссоздать имитацию сервера?

Comment: `Ubuntu Desktop и Ubuntu Server в ней` - здесь, пожалуйста, поподробнее.

Comment: Мануалов в сети вагон и маленькая тележка. Например, https://averagelinuxuser.com/ssh-into-virtualbox/ - первая выдача в Google по запросу `windows ssh to virtualbox vm`

Comment: Можно воспользоваться windows subsystem for linux (WSL) и установить интересующий дистрибутив штатными средствами windows. После чего подключение по ssh требоваться не будет с интерпретатором командной строки Linux можно будет работать локально

Answer (score 1):

Стандартное подключение

```
ssh ваш_IP_адрес_вашего_ubuntu_server
```

или же

```
ssh ваш_пользователь_на_ubuntu_server@ваш_IP_адрес_вашего_ubuntu_server
```

Само собой, на вашем сервере должен быть запущен `ssh server`.
Если он не установлен, то запустите там

```
sudo apt install openssh-server
```

Cледуйте инструкциям на экране.

Примеры:

```
ssh 192.168.0.100
ssh user@192.168.0.100
```

Comment: Только вот добыть `ваш_IP_адрес_вашего_ubuntu_server` для виртуальной машины задача в общем случае нетривиальная

Comment: Ну, как сказать. Если автор вопроса в теме хоть чуть в VMWare или Virtual Box и имеет доступ "к телу", то IP можно увидеть, - иначе, пусть пишет.

Comment: Если он задаёт такой вопрос, то скорее всего не в теме)

Comment: Согласен. Но мы же не можем предполагать, что автор не сегодня впервые увидел компьютер вообще. Компетенцию определим по комментариям, если соизволит-с.

Answer (score 1):

На Виндовс нужно установить ssh клиент. Для Виндовс 10:

Зайдите в «Параметры» —> «Приложения».
В поле приложение и возможности нажмите на пункте «Управление дополнительными компонентами».

Теперь нажмите кнопку «Добавить компонент». Это откроет список дополнительных функций, которые могут быть установлены. Большинство из них — это пакеты шрифтов, но если вы прокрутите вниз, увидите OpenSSH Client (beta) и OpenSSH Server (beta).

Для Виндовс 7,8 - скачайте putty или другой клиент.

Опенссх клиент лучше так как более приближен к большинству учебников Линукс.

В Putty подключение настраивается мышкой.

На Убунту в виртуалке в сборке сервер openssh server должен быть уже включён.

В Убунту десктоп установите его `sudo apt install openssh-server`.

Адрес сервера можно узнать в текстовой консоле( или терминале) выполнив команду `ip a`. Иногда показывает в свойствах виртуалки.

В powershell выполните `ssh user@ip`

Answer (score 0):

Для Windows можно использовать `PuTTY`

Чтобы каждый раз не вводить логин и пароль. Достаточно `создать ярлык приложения`. На ярлыке нажать `правой кнопке мыши` -> `"Свойства"`.

В поле "`Объект`" в конце после скобок добавить `username@ipAdress -pw password`
Например:  `"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" root@192.168.1.1 -pw 12345678`